# How to install earlier version of mongodb with homebrew?

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I'm on osx6.8 and need to install an earlier version of `Mongodb`, how do I install an earlier version with `HomeBrew`?

The below didn't work :(

```
dream-2:app2 star$ brew install mongodb-2.6.10
Error: No available formula for mongodb-2.6.10 
Searching formulae...
Searching taps...
dream-2:app2 star$
```

**Edit:**
I'm getting a message to explain how this post is unique compared to another one, well, the answer to the other question is super long and complex and it's specific to `postgresql` and doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When trying to install old versions of something with homebrew, it's usually useful to start with `brew search packagename`, in this case, there's a 2.6 version available under `homebrew/versions/mongodb26`

So, to install that version:

```
brew install homebrew/versions/mongodb26
```

### Edit

This answer has certainly become very dated. Take a look at the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47449979/259044) for a valid way to accomplish this in 2021.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it, terminal has hung I think, this was the last thing it said, (what does it mean?): 

`==> Installing mongodb26 from homebrew/homebrew-versions
==> Downloading https://fastdl.mongodb.org/src/mongodb-src-r2.6.8.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> /usr/local/opt/scons/bin/scons install --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb26/2.6.8 -j8 --cc=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 --cxx=/usr/bin/g++-4.2 --osx-version-min=10.6`

Comment: How long did you let it run before terminating it? That's just a typical homebrew installation. It's compiling mongodb from source, so it should take a couple minutes and you won't necessarily see any output.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that o.O! lol, I tried it again, eventually it loaded. Lot's of crazy messages on doing mongod -v but, maybe I can figure it out from here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `mongod --version` has much fewer 'crazy messages'. More specifically, `mongod -v` simply runs mongod in verbose mode, instead of displaying the version information. Good luck :)

Comment: Thank very much, great help. Why is -v different when used with mongod ? When I do node -v I get the version number o.O?!

Comment: what if I want to get 2.4.14? The above command will install 2.4.12!

Comment: To have launchd start homebrew/versions/mongodb26 now and restart at login: `brew services start homebrew/versions/mongodb26`; Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run: `mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`

Comment: I was just trying to install mongodb version 3.2 and your answer helped me a lot (`brew install homebrew/versions/mongodb32`), thank you! However, `brew search mongodb` didn't reveal **any** clue, that a version 3.2 was available and what the package name would be. Am I missing something? How can I search for all available versions?

Comment: This assumes you have an earlier version already installed. Some of the other answers are much better.

Comment: This answer seems a bit dated. `homebrew/versions was deprecated.`

Comment: Yeah, the answer below is much better than this one now.

Comment: This answer is not valid anymore since Brew team removed the old Mongodb package, the one bellow works better ( with the official tap from MongoDB team )

Answer (score 234):

> Note: In September 2019 `mongodb` was [removed](https://hub.packtpub.com/after-red-hat-homebrew-removes-mongodb-from-core-formulas-due-to-its-server-side-public-license-adoption/) from homebrew core, so these instructions have been updated to use `mongodb-community` instead, installed from the external tap.
>
> If your current installation is still the *pre-September* `mongodb` package then you will need to replace `mongodb-community` with just `mongodb` on the lines marked with `#*#` below.
>
> Another option is to simply [upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57881349/99777) away from the deprecated package now.

I already have the latest version of mongo installed, thanks to.

```
brew tap mongodb/brew

brew install mongodb-community
```

But I want to switch to the old version sometimes.  First, install it:

```
brew search mongo

brew install mongodb-community@3.2
```

Let's stop the current mongodb, if it is running:

```
brew services stop mongodb/brew/mongodb-community           #*#

# or if you had started it manually

killall mongod
```

Now I want 3.2 on my PATH instead of the latest:

```
brew unlink mongodb-community                               #*#

brew link --force mongodb-community@3.2
```

(Apparently it needs `--force` because it is keg-only.)

Now I have 3.2 on my PATH, I can start the test DB:

```
mongod --version

brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community

# or start your own mongod from the command-line
```

When I am finished, I can do the reverse to switch back to the latest version:

```
brew services stop mongodb/brew/mongodb-community

brew unlink mongodb-community@3.2

brew link mongodb-community                                 #*#

brew services start mongodb/brew/mongodb-community          #*#
```

And restart again.

Comment: Unsure why this is listed at the bottom, this is by far the best answer, and also the most upvoted

Comment: I got into a rabbit hole with different versions, and this is the only solution that worked for me.

Comment: brew now tells you after installing an alternate version of a formula (e.g. brew install mongodb@3.6) to set your $PATH via: `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mongodb@3.6/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Why this is not the answer? This actually helped me to solve, thanks tons!

Comment: @pnd Updating `PATH` is an alternative to relinking, but we must then `source ~/.bash_profile` in every open terminal we care about. I proposed `unlink` and `link` because that switches mongo version for the whole system, which may reduce confusion. Advanced users can certainly update `PATH` if they prefer.

Answer (score 4):

```
curl -O https://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.2.12.tgz
tar -zxvf mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.2.12.tgz
mkdir -p mongodb
cp -R -n mongodb-osx-x86_64-3.2.12/ mongodb
export PATH=<mongodb-install-directory>/bin:$PATH #path to the dir created in step 3
mkdir -p /data/db
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /data/
mongod
```

Comment: Homebrew just allows to install min 3.0. However, I need to use 2.6. Fortunately, your comment helped me to solve this and also helped me to install 2 version running at same time.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using homebrew you can use docker to install as many versions of mongodb as you want. Each mongodb can then run on separate ports.

Install docker with `brew cask install docker` and then open `Docker.app`. After docker is running, go to Terminal and install your mongodb version by selecting an image from https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/ like so: `docker run -d -p 28017:27017 --name mongo4 mongo:latest`

Verify that it's running with `docker ps` and you can connect to mongodb from your app using port 28017. Repeat the steps with a different name and port to install more versions. Enjoy!

Comment: how do i verify the version of mongodb running in this docker instance? I looked at docker 3 years ago but at the time it was a bit too none intuitive for me so i kept using vms, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Addition to the excellent answer of joeytwiddle :

if you don't want to link then unlink the old version of the software, you can just run it from the "cellar" (`/usr/local/Cellar/`), where brew installed it. 
Use `ls /usr/local/Cellar/` to find the exact path of the executable. For example in my case, to run mongo shell:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mongodb@3.6/3.6.7/bin/mongo
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to install it using these instructions:

> **Installing MongoDB on OSX for local development**
>
> Over the last week, I’ve been building our MongoDB cluster on EC2 for
>   production. For development, however, we’ll still need to install
>   MongoDB locally. I’m running OSX 10.6.8, but these install
>   instructions should be the same on all modern OSX versions.
>
> Installing on OSX is much more pleasant than on EC2 (actually it’s just as easy on EC2, but since it’s a simpler setup there’s n real configuration or
>   head scratching).
>
> Download the latest binary:
>
> `curl -O http://fastdl.mongodb.org/osx/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.0.2.tgz`
>
> **Note!:** If
>   you don’t have wget installed, simply download the file above by
>   visiting the link in your web browser and move it into your home
>   directory.
>
> We’re going to install everything under /usr/local/mongodb
>   to keep things organized.
>
> Create the directories (switch 'youruser' with your home user name):
>
> `sudo mkdir /usr/local/mongodb`
>
> `sudo mkdir /usr/local/mongodb/log`
>
> `sudo mkdir/usr/local/mongodb/data`
>
> `sudo chown youruser /usr/local/mongodb/log`
>
> `sudo chown youruser /usr/local/mongodb/data`
>
> `sudo chgrp staff /usr/local/mongodb/log`
>
> `sudo chgrp staff /usr/local/mongodb/data`
>
> Un-tar the binaries and move them into the correct folder:
>
> `tar -xvzf ~/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.0.2.tgz`
>
> `sudo mv ~/mongodb-osx-x86_64-2.0.2/* /usr/local/mongodb/`
>
> Create a config file for mongod:
>
> `sudo vi /usr/local/mongodb/mongod.conf`
>
> Paste:
>
> `dbpath=/usr/local/mongodb/data`
>
> `logpath=/usr/local/mongodb/log/mongod.log`
>
> `logappend=false`
>
> `bind_ip=127.0.0.1`
>
> Note: dbpath and logpath specify the path to their
>   respective files, logappend is set to overwrite the log file on each
>   start of the database server, bind_ip only allows local connections.
>
> Create an alias so that issuing mongod always read the config file:
>
> `vi ~/.profile`
>
> Paste:
>
> `# MongoDB Alias'`
>
> `alias mongod="/usr/local/mongodb/bin/mongod --config=/usr/local/mongodb/mongod.conf"`
>
> All done, you should be able to simply type mongod after you reload the shell to start MongoDB. I
>   preferred not to start mongod on boot, but there are other who prefer
>   to and there’s plenty of documentation online to show you how to set
>   that up with launchd and creating a .plist.

http://alexanderwong.me/post/15259867190/installing-mongodb-on-osx-for-local-development

Comment: sudo chown youruser /usr/local/mongodb/log

sudo chown youruser /usr/local/mongodb/data 

can be edited to 

sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/mongodb/log

sudo chown $(whoami) /usr/local/mongodb/data

Comment: Homebrew is the best tool for serious business. Breaking changes in the tool itself, breaking changes across versions of popular applications.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install an earlier MongoDB version on mac. Go to the link https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/ and select the version which you want to install and its very easy to install, just give a try. There will be around 2-3 commands for installation.

For example if you want to install **version 3.6**

```
brew tap mongodb/brew
brew install mongodb-community@3.6
```

If you got some error

```
If you need to have mongodb-community@3.6 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mongodb-community@3.6/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Then run

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mongodb-community@3.6/bin:$PATH"
```

To confirm if it successfully installed:

```
mongod -version
```