# How to use Homebrew to install Mongo 3.0.7?

Tags: macos, mongodb, homebrew

I read [How to install earlier version of mongodb with homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30379127/how-to-install-earlier-version-of-mongodb-with-homebrew), and

```
~> brew search mongo
homebrew/versions/libmongoclient-legacy               mongo-c                                             
homebrew/versions/mongodb24                           mongodb ✔                                         
homebrew/versions/mongodb26                           mongodb24                                           
libmongoclient                                        mongodb26                                           
libmongoclient-legacy                                 mongoose                                            
homebrew/php/php53-mongo                              Caskroom/cask/mongo-management-studio               
homebrew/php/php54-mongo                              Caskroom/cask/mongochef                             
homebrew/php/php54-mongodb                            Caskroom/cask/mongodb                               
homebrew/php/php55-mongo                              Caskroom/cask/mongodbpreferencepane                 
homebrew/php/php55-mongodb                            Caskroom/cask/mongohub                              
homebrew/php/php56-mongo                              Caskroom/cask/mongoproc                             
homebrew/php/php56-mongodb                            Caskroom/cask/orelord-mongodb                       
Caskroom/cask/jeromelebel-mongohub                    Caskroom/cask/robomongo
```

Looking at [homebrew versions](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions), there is no mongodb307 or mongodb.

How to use Homebrew to install Mongo 3.0.7?

Homebrew 0.9.5

Comment: Does `brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew/63468408a2f2ed1a6cdc467fbb7fc04541877e0d/Library/Formula/mongodb.rb` work? - In general homebrew does not tend to keep old versions around. Whenever a new one is released the old ones are usually replaced.

Comment: I did `git checkout 6ab5f0617ed36921c73ef3132d30e55b15169ea3` and it turns out that the OS is too old for 3.0.7.

Comment: I think I ended up using a more recent version.