# MongoDB installation throwing error with brew

Tags: mongodb, macos, terminal, homebrew

Hey I have tried everything out there and can't seem to find a solution to this. When I try installing MongoDB using brew on my mac with `brew install mongodb` in the terminal I get the following error:

```
mongodb: A full installation of Xcode.app 8.3.2 is required to compile this software.
```

I have ran a brew update and still facing the same issue, brew doctor shows a few other broken symlinks which don't seem to have anything to do with mongodb. Sorry if this has been answered before but there was nothing really that helpful online. Has this happened to anyone before or know how to fix this issue? thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongodb installation failed with homebrew and XCode 8.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251108/mongodb-installation-failed-with-homebrew-and-xcode-8-1-1)